# Couldn't Add two numbers and get the Total using Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to do a simple calculator program in asp.net MVC. I like to add two number and get the total. But I couldn't do the task. I am a beginner at `asp.net` MVC. code which I tried so far I attached below.

**Model**

```
namespace WebApplication30.Models
{
    public class cal
    {
        public int no1 { get; set; }
        public int no2 { get; set; }

        public int tot { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class CalController : Controller
{      
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(cal c)
    {
        c.tot = c.no1 + c.no2;

        return View(c);

    }

}
```

** This is a View pass the values from the controller**

```
@model WebApplication30.Models.cal
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "cal", FormMethod.Post))
        {

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="no">No 1</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no1" name="no1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">No 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no2" name="no2">
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">total</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tot" name="tot">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    }
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSV3u.jpg)

Comment: Normally you need to populate the model in the Controller and pass it to the View. I cannot see any Model in your View.

Comment: i edited the code above but tot is not displayed the total textbox no errors shown

Comment: i edited code again i hope understand now

Comment: Could you please explain what is the actual problem? Are you able to pass the input to the Controller? If you are getting an error please include it in the question.

Comment: i didn't get any error sir. when i click submit button tot is not displayed page is refreshed only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the input value to the cal Model. Also, need to add cal model when get index action called .

**CONTROLLER**

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WebApplication30.Models;

namespace WebApplication30
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new cal());
        }


      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Index(cal c)
      {
        c.tot = c.no1 + c.no2;

        return View(c);

      }
    }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@model WebApplication30.Models.cal
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<body>
<h2>Index</h2>

<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("/Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {

        <div class="form-group">
              <label for="no">No 1</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no1" name="no1" value="@Model.no1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">No 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no2" name="no2" value="@Model.no2">
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">total</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tot" name="tot" value="@Model.tot">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    }
</div>
</body>
```

*NOTE: add / before Index while submitting the form it creates sometimes a problem.*

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XRm6fW)

Comment: thanks you for your time sir it is working nice work